# What's the best way to compare two files & update the values of the first file from second file in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.6

I apologize for the nOOb question. I'm a newbie to Python & I'm using Python 2.6. I have two files and I need to compare both of them & update the value of the 1st file from the 2nd file.

My first file is as below,

```
SeqNo   City           State

1   Chicago         IL

2   Boston          MA

3   New York    NY

4   Los Angeles CA

5   Seattle         WA
```

My second file is as below,

```
SeqNo   City           State   NewSeqNo

5   Seattle     WA  1

1   Chicago         IL  2

4   Los Angeles CA  3

2   Boston          MA  4

3   New York    NY  5
```

How do I updated the SEQ Number in the first file with the value in the NewSeqNo from the second file?

For example, the output of the first file should be,

```
NewSeqNo   City           State

2   Chicago         IL

4   Boston          MA

5   New York    NY

3   Los Angeles CA

1   Seattle         WA
```

I need to achieve this using Python & any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are the values delimited? With tabs? If not, the city names should be quoted to avoid confusion with city names containing spaces

Answer (score 2):

Open the second file.  Use `csv.reader` to handle tokenizing each line.

Build up a mapping of oldseq->newseq, using a `dict`.

```
import csv

lookup = {}
with open('secondfile') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in reader:
        oldseq, city, state, newseq = line
        lookup[oldseq] = newseq
```

Now open up your first file.  Use the same strategy, but replace your `SeqNo` with the value in your mapping `dict`.

```
with open('firstfile') as f, open('outfile','w') as w:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    writer = csv.writer(w)
    for line in reader:
        seq, city, state = line
        if seq in lookup:
            seq = lookup[seq]
        writer.writerow([seq, city, state])
```

That's the gist of it.  You will have to deal with some small things that I didn't address, like skipping the header row(s), and renaming 'outfile' to 'firstfile' (ie overwriting the old file with the temporary file) once you're done with the operation.  It's *technically* possible to avoid creating a temporary file and directly write into your file as you're iterating over it, but I advise against it for reasons I won't delve into here.